# is there .NET native way to Auto Map properties of a source and target object?

Tags: .net

is there a native .NET way to Auto Map properties of a source and target object by the properties names ?

I know that i can use AutoMapper or build a mapping function myself, but i am looking for a way that is part of the native framework, like [Database.SqlQuery Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx) that map between Sp result to an object, but i need a way to do it for 2 non database object. Just between 2 POCOS.

Comment: As far as I know there is no automapper which is built in the .NET framework. Is there a special reason why you don't want to use AutoMapper?

Comment: You can create a typeconverter to convert from one type to another but it is not automaticly created for you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: You can do it by using a serializer that doesn't care about .net types. You serialize one object and deserialize another. But really, AM is the answer here.

Comment: Just have a research for .NET core 6 , Microsoft still no native or built-in way to do so.